# Create custom feedback mode in jshell

Tags: java-9, mode, feedback, jshell

As from the documentation of /set feedback in jshell, there are following built-in modes:

```
verbose, normal, concise, and silent
```

Is it possible to create a feedback mode with the functionality of both concise and silent? Or we can change any one of the above mode?
Or can we create our own custom feedback mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom feedback mode using the command:

```
/set mode <your-mode-name> -command|-quiet
```

where the `-command` option indicates that you want command feedback. If you don't want commands to describe the action that occurred, then use `-quiet` instead of `-command`.

If you want to copy an existing mode, you can do that as:

```
/set mode <your-mode-name> <existing-mode-name> -command|-quiet
```

For example

```
/set mode samplemode concise -command
```

In order to merge the functionality of both, you might have to edit the attributes from the command line for one that you didn't initially copy from.